# Access unreachable remote repository through a second party using tunneling (on eclipse)

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have the following setup:

- **Machine 1:** hosts a given svn repository and lives under a private network
- **Server:** lives under the same network as Machine 1 (therefore having access to it), but is also open to outside ssh connections.
- **Machine 2:** my personal computer which (when not under the same private network) can only access **Server**.

I would like to access **Machine 1** directly so that I can interact with the repository that it hosts using subversive on Eclipse. I can ssh to **Server** and from there ssh to **Machine 1** via terminal, but so far I haven't been able to figure out a way to do that on subversive. 
Any suggestion is much appreciated!

Ps.: All systems run linux

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) for your tunneling in such cases.

- It provides a proxy to connect to your host by localhost itself.
- It works on linux very well

PS: we have a similar architecture, and we use the same.

Comment: I only have sudo privileges to Machine 3. Would this approach be viable?

Comment: @EveraldoAguiar: if you sudo available on the machine from where you wish to connect, then there's nothing more you require. its enough. Depending upon your package manager, you can do `sudo apt-get install stunnel4`